# MVC5 routing in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having trouble configuring my routing. My routeconfig is as follow:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Somepage", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

now I have two controllers Sompage and Somepage2 and two views folder Somepage and Somepage2.
In my layout.cshtml, I have links to Somepage and Somepage2. Links to Somepage are working fine, however links to Somepage2 do not render. The link in layout file is

```
  @Html.ActionLink("some page on somepage2", "somepageonsomepage2", "Somepage2", new { target = "_blank" })
```

When I click this link it tries to take me to localhost/Somepage/somepageonsomepage2
when I want to go localhost/Somepage2/somepageonsomepage2

I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the correct overload of `ActionLink` that specifies your controller. By default an action link's controller will be view's controller. So if you have controller `HomeController` and view `Index` in folder `Home`, an action link's default controller will be `HomeController`

```
@Html.ActionLink("some page on somepage2", "somepageonsomepage2", "Somepage2", null, new { target = "_blank" })
```